# Why is Outlook 2007 suddenly saying on Behalf of?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, gmail

We send emails to clients and bcc each email sent to a few mailing lists. We re using:

- Google apps
- From email: is in our domain

We ve been doing this for a few months now but as of 11 am ET today, Outlook users on any of the mailing lists have been seeing: "From my-mailing-list@mydomain.com on behalf of Domain Emailer".

The process that sends the email uses SMTP through Javamail.

Answer (score 1):

In case some one is wondering why this happened. I inspected the email headers closely and found this:

Sender: my-mailing-list@mydomain.com

Google starting adding this yesterday and thats what caused Outlook to say "on behalf of" all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would need more details to understand the issue, the following two links should be able to help you out -

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/07/remove-on-behalf-of-from-messages-sent.html

Regards,

Comment: We re not using a different account to send the emails out. The from: is the same as the login. For some reason Outlook is showing the Return Path in the from as well.